# Defining GKSessionModeServer and GKSessionModeClient

Tags: iphone, objective-c, client-server, gamekit

My problem is that , I have to connect many devices using `GameKit` framework.
Everything works fine with two connections(`GKSessionModePeer`)
I searched a lot on internet on how to connect more than two devices and what I got is, to use `GKSessionModeServer` and `GKSessionModeClient`.I read the apple documentation also.

But still there is not any clear cut solution on how to use `GKSessionModeServer` and `GKSessionModeClient` means which device will act as server and which will act as client.

Please if any one know how to handle this or what approach should I follow, tell me.

Any help would be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I didnt try it with 3 devices ingame, but maybe this will help you (it worked with 5 devices in lobby).

1. I dont use GKSessionModeServer/Client, I use GKSessionModePeer.
2. I do autoconnect - it means that when new device shows up, other devices send connect request to it and it gets accepted automatically (so if we have 3 devices turned on, all of them are connected together)
3. Once you have all devices connected, you can send fake invitiations by sending normal data packets (I_INVITE_YOU, INVITATION_DECLINED, INVITATION_ACCEPTED) and then disconnecting other devices if you have enough players. You can add devices that disconnected you to you temporary ignore list - reset it if user goes back to main menu or sth
4. Once you have all the party ingame, they can decide who is who:
5. If you game doesnt send lots of data, you can do some simple checks against udid or peerid: lets say device with lowest udid is the SERVER, others are CLIENTS
6. If your game sends tons of data, I've observed that server should be THE SLOWEST machine - the thing is that when server is fast (works with lets say 50fps), it sends data at similar framerate, so when client is slow (lets say 20fps), it gets about 2 packets from server per frame, which further slows it down. Question is how to decide which device is slowest. I used average fps

it sounds a bit complicated but works much better than standard ios invitation scheme (it was traumatic experience with 3.1)

Regards!

Comment: thanks a lot for your answer,Yes you are right but my requirement is that whenever a user clicks on device then an acceptation request will go.I cannnot do automatic connection with all the devices showing in the list.Please suggest something else.

Comment: ok. then the simplest solution is to have two menu options: PLAY AS SERVER and PLAY AS CLIENT

Comment: can you please elaborate what do you mean by SERVER and CLIENT.Please.

Comment: not sure what you mean, but I will try to explain better: if we are talking about the games: SERVER is one of the machines which controls the action - it makes decisions (who lives, who dies, what explodes) and transfers output to other machines which are CLIENTS. CLIENTS are using data from SERVER to visualize things, plus they send user input to SERVER (screen touches etc). CLIENTS dont make any decisions.

Comment: in terms of ios ModeServer and ModeClient is mostly about their visibility - clients can see and connect to server, server can see clients. server doesnt see server and client doesnt see client (I am not 100% sure about the last statement).

Comment: so there are two ways to implement connection between devices: one is to use ModeServer and ModeClient provided by apple ios, and another one is to use ModePeer and decide who is who after connection is established